# Why can't I select inside these input boxes?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a dummy form in CodePen and in the middle row I wanted to have two input boxes next to each other taking up 50% each in the row. I was able to do this, however, I cannot click inside either input box to start typing. The only way I can start typing in each input is to start at the first box and press 'tab'. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Application for Philadelphia Eagles</h1>
  <h2><strong>Position:</strong> Wide Receiver</h2>
  <p>An attempt at Input label floats</p>
  <form class="form-container">
    <div class="form-tr">
      <div class="tc-100"><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-tr">
      <div class="tc-50 flt-l"><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="tc-50 flt-r"><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-tr">
      <div class="tc-100"><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:400,300,700');

body {
  font-family: Josefin Slab, sans-serif;
}
h1, h2 {margin: 0.465em}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
}
.flt-l { float:left; }
.flt-r { float:right; }
.form-container {
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width:40em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-tr {
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width:100%;
}
.tc-50  {
  width:50%;
}
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=text] {
  font-size:1em;
  padding:1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

My CodePen here: http://codepen.io/mjdeangelis/pen/avpBex?editors=110

Comment: in a browser that has debugging tools such as chrome, right click where you think the input should be and choose "inspect element". You can see in this case that the div containing the bottom input is covering those middle inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another fix is removing the position:relative property from the form-tr on the CSS file since the outer form container already has it and in this case its making the 2 inputs in the middle overlap.

Before:

```
.form-tr {
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width:100%;
}
```

After:

```
.form-tr {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width:100%;
}
```

For extra references you can always check out the following links:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your classes like:

```
.flt-l {
  float:left;
}

.flt-r {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: but `flt-r` means `float:right`. it's a utility class

Comment: Hi @danyamachine, i only tried to fix the error changing his code at minimun, but thanks for the point.

Answer (score 1):

The third row is overlapping with second row, hence not clickable. Provide a height to the second row, so that third row is pushed below it.

Updated code is available here

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOjjYE?editors=110

```
.split-row{
  height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set form-tr height to match the height of your full-width rows.

```
.form-tr {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If  you can remove "position: relative" in class, it also works.

```
.form-tr {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width:100%;
}
```